# IE FileReader prints out "\n"

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I have an XML File that I need to read into a string and pass that string to a DOMParser object. All that works just fine in FF and Chrome, but IE has the complicate things as per usual.

Take for example this XML structure:

```
<person>
    <firstname>John</firstname>
    <lastname>Doe</lastname>
</person>
```

FireFox and Chrome give me this string:

```
"<person>
    <firstname>John</firstname>
    <lastname>Doe</lastname>
</person>"
```

and IE gives me this string:

```
"<person>\n <firstname>John</firstname>\n <lastname>Doe</lastname>\n </person>"
```

as you can see, IE prints out the \n explicitly and prints everything on a single line. This causes a problem when I pass onto a DOMParser as it doesn't know how to handle the \n characters.

I use FileReader() for reading in the file and DOMParser() for parsing the string produced by the FileReader.

I'm not sure how to remedy this problem, any help?

Comment: The bug sounds more to be in the DOMParser... It should accept `\n` without problem, just for the test, can you try to hardcode new lines with `\r\n`, my VM is off, but I think I remember it's how windows encodes new lines.

Comment: your comment made me mess around with the output of IE and it seems that it escapes the strings as well so an attribute on the person tag would get escaped as well. And no matter what I do, IE seems to instantly apply all of it's formatting again the second I remove it.
Why does Microsoft always have to be the odd one out... ;l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string itself still contains the `\n` characters, the only difference is that IE displays them raw and Chrome and Firefox show them as line breaks.

If you open up the console in either Chrome or Firefox and type `"a\nb"` you'll get the output as two different lines. The `length` of the string is still 3 characters, but the browser console converts the newline characters into new lines.

If this is definitely a problem, then you can always use `replace()` on the string to strip any newline characters:

```
"<person>\n ... \n </person>".replace(/\n/g, "")
```

Comment: You were right. IE debugger shows them raw, but if you use console.log or some other method to print it out it doesn't print them out raw. The problem appears to be related with the DOMParser, but I only get the ever so useful error message "Unspecified Error".